# Genric function to return List with specified type

Tags: generics, kotlin

Below code snippet returns class type Object, so no casting is required.

```
fun <T: Any> getData(clazz: KClass<T>): T? {

}

// Calling function
val article = getData(Article::class)
article.read == true      // Call function is possible without casting
```

Now what I would like to do is to return `List` with a specific `Type`. However, as the `::class`'s left side should be only class I can't pass something like that `List<Article>::class`.

How could this be solved?

**Method 1.** Create a class that extends `List<Article>` and pass that class as a parameter

```
class ArticleList: ArrayList<Article>


fun <T: Any> getData(clazz: KClass<T>): T? {

}

// Calling function
val articleList = getData(ArticleList::class)
articleList[0].read == true      // Call function is possible without casting
```

**Method 2.** Change input parameter of `getData()` function to `Type` and add paramaterType in front of `getData()` function everytime it's called.

```
fun <T: Any> getData(type: Type): T? {
} 

// Calling function
val listType = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Article>>() {}.type
val data = getData<List<Article>>(listType)
data[0].read == 1     // Call function is possible without casting
```

Currently, I'm trying to avoid *method 1* because I'll end up creating a class for every item and *method 2* is already kind of casting.

Is there any other solution to achieve in the simplest way possible?

Comment: Can you show in code what's the method 2?

Comment: @FARID good question. what is the concrete use-case for this (just out of interest)?

Comment: @FARID I would suggest removing the android tag since it is a question which only concerns pure Kotlin.

Comment: @WilliMentzel Removed. I'm caching unknown-type data from the server which could be CustomObject or List<CustomObject>

Comment: @RikeshSubedi I don't instantiate, I'm caching data directly from the server and hold key to every value. Depending on the section of app `getData()` should return `List<CustomObject>` or `CustomObject`. Say, in one section I'm requesting profile info in another section messages list. So just passing key and data type, I should be able to do modification on the data without casting.

Answer (score 2):

btw, you can use `reified` type parameters of `inline` function to not pass `KClass` object:

```
inline fun <reified T> getData(): T? {
    // do something with T::class
}
```

This is not an ideal solution but you can create an additional `getDataList` function:

```
inline fun <reified T> getDataList(): List<T> {
    val listType = TypeToken.getParameterized(List::class.java, T::class.java)
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Upvoting for a reason)). Actually, the function with the reified parameter is what I'm avoiding as I still have to pass typeParameter when calling function, see my `method 2` and the reason I'm avoiding it.

Answer (score 0):

What's the overhead in passing actual type rather than Type parameter?

Since I am also new to Kotlin. Here's is what I came up with.

```
class Article {
    var read = false
}

inline fun <reified T> getData() : T? {
    //how do I generically instantiate T, I don't have constructor info here
    for(con in T::class.java.constructors) {
        if(con.parameterCount == 0) {
            return con.newInstance() as T
        }
    }
    return null
}
fun main(){
    val article = getData<Article>() 
    article?.read = true
    var articleList = getData<ArrayList<Article>>() 
    article?.let{
        articleList?.add(it)
    }
    print(articleList)
}
```